# WYSIWYG Editor gone missing

Tags: ee2, editor, ckeditor

We have EE 2.1.0.

One of our Super Admins actually had some WYSIWYG editor for the content in entries. I have never seen a WYSIWYG editor and I'm a Super Admin as well.

I don't see that we have any plugins or extensions installed.

The "Center Content" field in the entries shows as Wygwam type.
I'm also showing a Wygwam Field Type (v2.0.4) but it has no License Key entered. I know this has worked before. I don't want to uninstall it because it will remove all content with that field type and I've got TONS of it.

Why would she have that and now today, no longer has it?

BTW, for some reason, I can't post new topics on the EllisLab forums, did they "mothball" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the URL to the themes folder was not https:

`http://www.example.com/themes/` vs. `https://www.example.com/themes/`

This caused the resources to load in mixed mode causing the issue.